# database connectivity fails after creating jar file

Tags: java, mysql, jar, connectivity

I created a project with notepad.And running well in cmd with mysql server database.

But after creating a jar file of same project then jar file is not able to connect to the server database.so don't know what to do next? Even though other systems (only installed java not mysql) are unable to connect to the server database after running from either cmd or jar file.

---

Is it necessary for every systems to have java and mysql installed on other systems to run? How to overcome from such problem. I want to distribute it to the users but i am unable to do that...
code--->`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

```
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://serverhostname:3306/databasename"‌​,"username","password");
```

Comment: If you didn't have a remote MySQL server, I'm pretty sure that you'll need to configure a local MySQL server to run you code.

Comment: but i don't want my systems to be connected as a remote computer.Actually i have paid hosting and they offered me mysql server apart from domain.Not i created tables on server and my system(only) able to connect to the server and can retrieve every thing.But other systems are not able to connect to it..and after creating jar file,my system is not able to connect to it.

Comment: How you are creating jar ?

Comment: I made a manifest.txt file in the same directory with Main-Class:anil and one empty line. and then executed it from cmd as jar -cvfm anil.jar manifest.txt *.class

Comment: put the code by which you are making the database connection

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself it's illegibile. Edit it into your question.

Comment: how you are running the `jar`?

Comment: by directly accessing the location of the jar file and then double click on that jar file.

Comment: please anyone help me regarding this problem...i need to do it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution,
following are the content of manifest.txt file

```
Main-Class: filename
Class-Path: . mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar
```

mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar connector must be in the same directory so that the jar file include it.
This connector can be easily downloaded or can be found in mysql folder under program files 
After that from the cmd, command must be executed

```
jar -cvfm jarfilename.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

A new jar file will be created based upon your class file and manifest,then it can be easily runnable with double click and the server will respond same as that of cmd mode.